# Excel sheet value comparison

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have two excel sheets: one has all the data I need, and the other is missing some. How do I compare the sheets to figure out which data from the first sheet has been excluded from the second?
I have about 600 addresses in these sheets, and sent the sheet off to a company that adds names to them. They only included addresses in their excel for which names were found, but I'd like to know which addresses were left out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SuperUser. please let us know what have you tried so far to get your task done, and if possible give us further details on how your data is sctructured.

Comment: Export the sheets to CSV files and use text file tools.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will return 0 if the address is not in Sheet2, and otherwise a number equal to how many times the address is in Sheet2, (If there is a match with no duplicates, it returns 1.)

```
 =SUM(IF(A1=Sheet2!$A$1:$H$18,1,0))
```

I've assumed the first address in Sheet1 is in cell A1 and that your data are in cells A1:H18 in Sheet2. I don't know if the Sheet2 addresses are in a single column; if they are you can reference that column instead of the whole data range in Sheet2.

This is an array formula and needs to be entered with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination. It can then be copied down to the end of the addresses in Sheet1.